# Symfony Role Rules for Routes - Access Denied

Tags: symfony, authentication, roles

I am having issues securing a route 'dashboard' to a custom user role. I am using FOSUserBundle and I am aware that due to due users are given ROLE_USER by default - even though this role does appear in the user table.

On a user sign in (this happens via Steam) I add a new custom

```
$user->setRoles(['ROLE_LOGGED_STEAM_USER']);
```

My issue flows as such - User hits site - User logs in - redirect to Dashboard route - with the access denied error.

I have also disabled the security line and dumping out the ROLES to which I can pull from the token user object to confirm the ROLE exists and matches the rule

Here is my security ACL

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    steamauth:
        id: steam.user_provider
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        provider: steamauth
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
        form_login:
            login_path:   login
            check_path:   login_check
        steam:
            default_route: controller.dashboard.home

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/dashboard, role: ROLE_LOGGED_STEAM_USER }
```

Initially, I wasn't aware that all roles had to Begin with ROLE_*

Here is a screenshot of the user entry with the role attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv85b.png)

I hope its somthing simple im just overlooked so any help would be great!

Thanks it advance for any help/suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think you have a typo, please try changing role to roleS wtih "s"

```
 - { path: ^/dashboard, roles: ROLE_LOGGED_STEAM_USER }
```

Comment: Hey @Smaïne thanks i gave that a try and sadly no avail - good thought though

Answer (score 0):

I think you must register your custom role on the "**role_hierarchy**" so the code will be:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_LOGGED_STEAM_USER]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

Hope it help.

Comment: Thanks for commenting - i had tried this too but it dosent work ethier